# How to compile ES6+ code to ES6 with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

I want to compile my code to ES6 not ES5.
Here is my babelrc.

```
{
"presets": [
    [
        "env",
        {
            "modules": false,
            "useBuiltIns": true,
            "targets": {
                "browsers": ["Chrome >= 60"]
            }
        }
    ],
    ["react"],
    ["stage-2"]
]}
```

And with babel-cli, the right ES6 code can be compiled.
For example

[image]

But when I use **webpack**, **babel-loader** in the same babel config, my ES6 code was compiled to ES5.

So how can i compile ES6+ code to ES6+ with Webpack?

Does webpack compile ES6+ code to ES5 ?

Comment: can you add the webpack configuration to question?

Comment: Did you tried `"browsers": ["last 2 Chrome versions"]` ?

Comment: Thanks. I found my error. I insert two babel-loader, one use es5 config, the other use es6 config. So sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's option target option `esmodules`. check it out [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targetsesmodules).

```
{
"presets": [
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "modules": false,
            "useBuiltIns": true,
            "targets": {
                "browsers": ["Chrome >= 60"],
                "esmodules": true
            }
        }
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-react"]
]}
```